# Databricks REST API: move Repo to Workspace Folder

Tags: databricks, databricks-cli, databricks-rest-api

I am using the Python [Databricks REST API](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/python-api.html).
I create folder in the workspace:

```
workspace_api = WorkspaceApi(api_client)    
workspace_api.mkdirs("/Users/xxxx/myfirstrepo")
```

Then, I checkout a repo:

```
repos_api = ReposApi(api_client)
repos_api.create("https://github.com/xxx","github","/Repos/xxx/freshRepo")
```

Now, I want to copy the content of the repo to the workspace folder `myfirstrepo`. How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this as a single operation - these are different object types.

There are few approaches to that:

- checkout the Git repository to the local disk and then use `import_dir` command from the Databricks CLI ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/workspace-cli.html#import-a-directory-from-your-local-filesystem-into-a-workspace))
- list all files in repository, export each file with [REST API export command](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/workspace.html#export), and then import it with corresponding [REST API command](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/workspace.html#import)